# Cassandra CQL alternative to OR in WHERE clause

Tags: cassandra, cql

Here's the code I used to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE test.packages (
     packageuuid timeuuid, 
     ruserid text, 
     suserid text, 
     timestamp int, 
     PRIMARY KEY (ruserid, suserid, packageuuid, timestamp)
);
```

and then I create a materialized view:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW test.packages_by_userid 
    AS SELECT * FROM test.packages 
    WHERE ruserid IS NOT NULL 
       AND suserid IS NOT NULL 
       AND TIMESTAMP IS NOT NULL 
       AND packageuuid IS NOT NULL 
    PRIMARY KEY (ruserid, suserid, timestamp, packageuuid) 
    WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (packageuuid DESC);
```

I want to be able to search for packages sent between two IDs

so I would need something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM test.packages_by_userid WHERE (ruserid = '1' AND suserid = '2' AND suserid = '1' AND ruserid = '2') AND timestamp > 1496601553;
```

How would I accomplish something like this with CQL?

I've searched a bit but I can't figure it out.

I'm willing to change the structure of the table if it will make something like this possible.

If it's doable without a materialized view that would also be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use In Clause:**

```
SELECT * FROM test.packages_by_userid WHERE ruserid IN ( '1', '2') AND suserid IN ( '1','2') AND timestamp > 1496601553;
```

Note : *Keep the in clause size smaller, Large in clause in the partition can cause GC pauses and heap pressure that leads to overall slower performance*

> In practical terms this means you’re waiting on this single coordinator node to give you a response, it’s keeping all those queries and their responses in the heap, and if one of those queries fails, or the coordinator fails, you have to retry the whole thing.

If the multiple partition in clause larger try to use separate query, for each partition (`ruserid`) with [executeAsync](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/java-driver-async-queries).

```
SELECT * FROM test.packages_by_userid WHERE ruserid = '1' AND suserid IN ( '1','2') AND timestamp > 1496601553;
SELECT * FROM test.packages_by_userid WHERE ruserid = '2' AND suserid IN ( '1','2') AND timestamp > 1496601553;
```

Learn More : https://lostechies.com/ryansvihla/2014/09/22/cassandra-query-patterns-not-using-the-in-query-for-multiple-partitions/

Comment: Thanks again! The in clause will always involve two user IDs, so hopefully I don't have a problem with slowdowns.

Comment: That's great, then you can use in clause solution without any doubts.

Comment: I've never seen the CQL syntax *ruserid IN ( '1', '2') AND suserid IN ( '1','2')* with a double *IN* clause. In which Cassandra version is this syntax valid? Did you mean *(ruserid, suserid) IN (('1', '2'), ('1','2'))*?

Comment: @xmas79 this is valid in Cassandra 3.0 and up

Answer (score 0):

Since you always search for both sender and receiver, I'd model this with the following table layout:

```
CREATE TABLE test.packages (
     ruserid text, 
     suserid text, 
     timestamp int, 
     packageuuid timeuuid, 
     PRIMARY KEY ((ruserid, suserid), timestamp)
);
```

In this way, for each pair of sender/receiver you need to run two queries, one for each partition:

```
SELECT * FROM packages WHERE ruserid=1 AND suserid=2 AND timestamp > 1496601553;
SELECT * FROM packages WHERE ruserid=2 AND suserid=1 AND timestamp > 1496601553;
```

This is IMHO the best solution because, remember, in Cassandra you start from your queries and build your table models on that, never the reverse.